# how to handle microservice database relations?

Tags: database, rest, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am working on a sample microservice project.
I have teacher-service, student-service, studies-service, and sports-service.
I used database per service pattern

a teacher has many students
a student has many studies data and sports data
the teacher may change for students

- how to handle the relationship?

and the teacher wants to see his students studies and sports data

- what is the best way to handle this situation in microservices

I tried by storing students id in teacher-service

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      teacher_id     |     student_id   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

but in studies-service and sports-service I am only storing student_id.

to get teacher's students studies and sports data. I take all student id of the teacher from teacher-service and pass it to studies-service, and sports-service.

I pass the student id by Rest GET method and its getting longer

=====> update.

how about storing teacher_id and student_id in all databases (duplicate data with consistancy) or using a in 3rd database (a sharded database)

Comment: The approach you are using is valid, try to use Feign Client (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) to reduce boiler-plate code and try to make your external service highly available. Also create multiple instance and balance it.

Comment: Microservice A calls microservice B for student details, and may ask microservice C for another details as well, and so on.

Comment: but @YogeshPrajapati, GET method has a character limit if we pass all student _id API may reject, and if use pagination we need to call this all time. how to handle this

Comment: Ohhh, sorry i misunderstood your question. You should not pass all ids at once to another service via GET

Comment: but in Rest Get is used for quering, how to replace in with other methods

Comment: If the GET call parameter-numbers are growing and if that is an issue, try with POST call. Violating REST rule is okay if the situation is forcing you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you haven't fully explored the domain and are rushing to figure out how to create database relationships. For now, don't focus on where the database keys are stored, because *this is no longer a 3rd-normal-form* database design.

Think in terms of [bounded contexts](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). The context of a teacher may be very small--the teacher doesn't 'own' anything other than skills. A subject has many classes/sections which each own a teacher and students. A sport will have coaches and students.

Thinking about it like that will help you figure out what services need to contain references to resources outside their own context.

Comment: I believe that is the right answer.
It is unclear for example what the 'studies' represent? It can be a set of studies the school offers or it can be student`s studies data, both would be stored differently.